# Parsing to double and ignoring letters and whitespace

Tags: c#, webforms

I define the prices here:

```
lblPrisGrill.Text = "20,00 ,-"; // Grill
lblPrisWiener.Text = "25,00 ,-"; // Wiener
lblPrisBacon.Text = "35,00 ,-"; // Bacon
lblPrisOst.Text = "30,00 ,-"; // Oste
```

I parse the price from string to double (number):

```
if (rbGrill.Checked == true)
    PrisMeny = double.Parse(lblPrisGrill.Text);

else if (rbWiener.Checked == true)
    PrisMeny = double.Parse(lblPrisWiener.Text);

else if (rbBacon.Checked == true)
    PrisMeny = double.Parse(lblPrisBacon.Text);

else if (rbOst.Checked == true)
    PrisMeny = double.Parse(lblPrisOst.Text);
```

I would like to know how I could only get the number `"##,##"` and ignore the `" ,-"`.

I know there exists resources explaining this, but I would like to know how this would be if I have multiple tasks and see how it would be done.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use `String.Replace` to remove that part:

```
string s = "20,00 ,-";

double d = double.Parse(s.Replace(",-", ""));
Console.WriteLine(d); // 20.0
```

Comment: why not include the  space that way you don't need to call trim

Comment: @Sorceri I wanted to get rid of any whitespace, since this appears to be user input, but it turns out, that `double.Parse` handles whitespace around the number just fine. (Also not including the space there makes sure that the replacement doesn’t fail if the space is forgotten at some point later)

Answer (score 0):

You can use Regex to find the matched expression. I have created [this](https://dotnetfiddle.net/cxdFYR) dotnet fiddle to demonstrate your scenario. You can check the output in fiddle. Attaching the code for reference.

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var text = "200,001 ,-"; 

        var regex = new Regex(@"\d\d*,\d\d*");
        foreach(var match in regex.Matches(text))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(match.ToString());
        }

    }
}
```